# Can't figure out which path to refer for deleting file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I am trying to delete a file from the public storage in laravel using `Storage::delete()` method. The given path for the file is `'avatars\image.jpg'` the file is stored in `app\storage\public\avatars`  and the storage has already been linked so I can refer to my files in the public folder of the project. I think I am passing the wrong path to the delete method but I can't figure out which one to pass.

Default disk is actually public and O am passing 'avatars/image.jpg'

Comment: what path are you passing? what is set as your default disk?

Comment: Just edited with the informations

Comment: so this `avatars` folder is in `storage/app/public/avatars` ?

Comment: Yes exactly in that folder

Comment: assuming that `public` disk is setup as default, it seems that `avatars/image.jpg` is the path you should be using ... unless you have something going on like `.../avatars/avatars/image.jpg` (assuming i didn't ask the wrong question or read incorrectly)